# Can Snow Leopard Servers`s File Sharing (AFP), iCal, and iChat be updated without user logins/accounts and by individual iMacs?

Tags: sharing, ical, osx-server, ichat

My supervisor wants this setup.  We have the internet service provider connected to a switch, and the switch has Snow Leopard Server and 5 iMacs connected to it.

Is it possible to use File Sharing, iCal, and iChat without user logins/accounts from the 5 iMacs?

I know in Workgroup Manager you can:
1.  Create Computer Accounts
2.  Create Computer Groups
3.  Add Computers to Computer Groups

If you can do this in Workgroup Manager, can you use File Sharing (AFP), iCal, and iChat without user logins/accounts?

Comment: Welcome to the site - this is a very large question. You might try splitting things up to get the best answers that stand alone and don't require a lot of back and forth. It also helps when there is an unambiguous answer - setting up server is a very ambiguous endeavor in totality.

Comment: If you didn't have accounts in iChat, how would you know who you were talking to?

Answer (score 1):

Macs always have a user account - even if it's the root user or a temporary guest account that gets deleted each log out.

You could issue iPads and sidestep user accounts and just serve up files, calendars and chats.

Answer (score 0):

No. Computer accounts and groups are only used for preference management (e.g. if you log into this computer, you should get certain apps added to your Dock). They cannot be used to log in or access services.